# Firestore security rules: what happens with request.resource.data.<prop> on update?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My team has discussed this lately, and can't seem to determine for sure actual/intended behavior:

If you have a security rule like the following:

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
    allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
    && request.resource.data.firstName is string
    && request.resource.data.lastName is string;
}
```

And you create an update statement from the frontend to /categories/ with the following data:

```
{
   firstName: 'A valid firstName'
}
```

Is the security rule then supposed to pass or fail?

In the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/), it says that

> Developer provided data is surfaced in request.resource.data, which
>   is a map containing the fields and values. Fields not provided in the
>   request which exist in the resource are added to
>   request.resource.data

Related questions:

1. Does this mean that the success/fail depends on the existing data in
   the node?
2. What happens if someone tries to update with data not
   specified in the security rule, i.e. `{age: 28}`
3. What is the
   recommended way to validate update data?

**Question 3 with more details (schema question)**
Suppose you have a model like this:

```
interface Category {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age?: int;
  groupId?: string;
}
```

Now we create a security rule like this:

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
    allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
    && request.resource.data.firstName is string
    && request.resource.data.lastName is string;
    && request.resource.data.age is int;
    && request.resource.data.groupId is string;
}
```

Then we have the following scenario, as I understand:
[image]

*None* of those scenarios fits well with optional properties. Because if you have to provide all properties (like in scenario 1) it is not really optional properties. And if you don't provide them, like in scenario 2, it fails.

Maybe I am missing something here, a basic guide on how to validate data with optional properties being written to firestore?

A security rule for an optional parameter, something like this:

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
   allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
   && request.resource.data.firstName is string
   && request.resource.data.lastName is string;
   && request.resource.data.age is int; // ignore if NOT provided
   && request.resource.data.groupId is string; // ignore if NOT provided
}
```

Answer (score 12):

> Is the security rule then supposed to pass or fail?

That update will succeed if the document being updated already has a `lastName` field and this field is a `string`. (I'm assuming you're running this update while authenticated so that `request.auth.uid != null` returns true)

Answering the Related questions:

1. Yes, sometimes it might depend on the existing data on the node.
2. If that document already has a `firstName` and `lastName` set, adding the `age` field will succeed. Note that the rule only checks if these 2 values are strings. It doesn't specify that the document can't have more than 2 fields.
3. That question sounds a little broad (kinda like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/364194) I would say). Please explain what kind of update validation you're trying to do. Based on your questions I already have an idea of what you're trying, but I want to be 100% sure.

**Update**:

What I understood from your updated question 3 is that you want to only update the document if the user provided both first and last names. The age and groupId are optional.

To do that, you can check if this `request.resource.data.firstName` is not the one already on the database using: `resource.data.firstName != request.resource.data.firstName`. So your security rules would look like this:

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
   allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
   && (request.resource.data.firstName is string && resource.data.firstName != request.resource.data.firstName)
   && (request.resource.data.lastName is string && resource.data.firstName != request.resource.data.firstName)
   && request.resource.data.age is int
   && request.resource.data.groupId is string
}
```

Now with these rules, an update with this data will fail:

```
{
   firstName: 'A valid firstName'
}
```

While these 3 will succeed:

```
{
   firstName: 'A valid firstName',
   lastName: 'A valid lastName'
}

{
   firstName: 'A valid firstName',
   lastName: 'A valid lastName',
   age: 20
}

{
   firstName: 'A valid firstName',
   lastName: 'A valid lastName',
   age: 20,
   groupId: 'groupId'
}
```

**Update 2:** To have `age` and `groupId` as optional fields, use the OR operator and the `hasAll()` function to check if the request has these fields:

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
   allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
   && (request.resource.data.firstName is string && resource.data.firstName != request.resource.data.firstName)
   && (request.resource.data.lastName is string && resource.data.firstName != request.resource.data.firstName)
   || (request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['age']) && request.resource.data.age is int)
   || (request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['groupId']) && request.resource.data.groupId is string)
}
```

Comment: Hi Rosario - thanks for the answer. I don't think it is a XY problem because after all, is the purpose of security rules not to help validate data? I added more details to the question :)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've updated my answer as well

Comment: I looked into your answer, and I came to the conclusion that you are only partial right in your answer. You state: "While these 3 will succeed". But I don't think that is the case. On the first case, creating with firstName and lastName, will fail because the security rule tests for request.resource.data.age and request.resource.groupId.

Comment: The security rules tests if age is int and groupId is string. Don't forget that Fields not provided in the request which exist in the resource are added to request.resource.data ... If this age already exists in the database and it is an int, the rule will succeed.

Comment: That is my point. The first one (`{firstName: 'A valid firstname', lastName: 'A valid lastanem'}`) will fail if no data exists! And thats is not good, because age and groupId are optional parameters.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I misunderstood at first. I've updated my answer with the correct approach

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. But the updated security rule does not work. I tried providing invalid data, and the update went straight through - I'm sorry. But thanks for trying to help with how to achieve optional parameters.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes according to your **Update 2** this statement `{
   firstName: 'A valid firstName',
age: 23
}` will unintendedly succeed, as it would evaluate the rules like `true && true && false || true || false`